# Filling the client area of a window with client area of internet browser

Tags: c++, c, winapi, browser, window

I am working on a program that would create a window with no title bar which has the WM_CLOSE message procedure set to return 0. So far, I got this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowEventProc(HWND hWindow, UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT Paint;
    HDC hdc;
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_DESTOY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);
            return 0;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            return 0;
        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc=BeginPaint(hWindow,&Paint);
                //here should go the code for painting
            EndPaint(hWindow, &Paint);
            return 0L; 
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWindow, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int nCmdShow)
{
    GetDesktopSize(h,w);
    WNDCLASSEX KlasaOkna;
    ZeroMemory (&KlasaOkna, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    KlasaOkna.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    KlasaOkna.hInstance = hInstance;
    KlasaOkna.lpfnWndProc = WindowEventProc;
    KlasaOkna.lpszClassName = Name.c_str();
    KlasaOkna.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    KlasaOkna.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    KlasaOkna.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_WINDOW;
    RegisterClassEx (&KlasaOkna);

    HWND hwn;
    hwn = CreateWindowEx(NULL,Name.c_str(),"",WS_MYSET,0,0,w,h,NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL);

    SetWindowPos(hwn,HWND_TOPMOST,0,0,w,h,NULL);
    SetWindowLong(hwn, GWL_STYLE, 0);

    ShowWindow (hwn, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage (&msg);
        DispatchMessage (&msg);
    }
}
```

which works as intended, but now comes the hardest thing - I'd like the window to open a website in its client area. I think the best way to maintain the site's functionality is opening it through a browser. There surely is a way to paint an internet browser into my window, but I cannot think of any, neither could I find it in MSDN. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly possible, but not trivial. Embed WebKit.

The Microsoft solution would be to embed Trident, as an ActiveX component.